# Working with Googles API's in front end or backend?

Tags: spring, reactjs, api, oauth-2.0, google-api

I just started to work with Google API's (Calendar and Gmail for now). I already got both examples working on both my Frontend (React) and my Backend (Java - Spring).

I have the following doubt, If I want to enable users to be able to send email's using the oficial API **not javax.mail** should that be done on the Backend or it can be done on Frontend? Since the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js?hl=es-419) only shows examples on Java and Python.

If the answer is on Backend how will users be able to authenticate via OAuth2 If they are "not supposed" to see server-side information.

Thanks

Comment: You could have your users go through the usual OAuth2 flow, and then expose their `access_token` to the browser and do API calls from there, if the use case is right.

Comment: Sorry, not really getting the hang of it. You mean they authenticate in the Frontend side and then actually send their access-token to Backend to process data?

Comment: You can use the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to take yourself through a standard OAuth flow. All this would have to be handled by your server, but the `access_token` you get in the final step can be sent to the user's browser and used from there.

Comment: If all logic is already handled on Backend, why would I need to send it to Front?

Comment: There might be use cases where you don't want unnecessary traffic to go through your server, but instead let all requests go straight from the browser to Google's APIs, instead of using your server as a middleman. Doing it all on the server is much easier though, so if you don't have a problem with traffic, it's probably wise to keep it all in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for does looking for an answer. I found the following guide...

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret

Basically you can get a client-side one time access code which is send to server-side where it can get a long-live access_token in order to have offline access once correct authentication has happened.